# How to create animation with scale property in firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have an image with `align:=client` and `scale.X:=0,5` and `scale.Y:=0,5` and `wrapmode:=Center`

I have created a `TFloatAnimation` on `Scale.X` and `Scale.Y` properties
with these properties:

```
AnimationType:=in
duration:=0,2
Enabled:=true
Interpolation:=linear
StartFromCurrent:=true
StopValue:=1
```

but when the animation begins it works and the scale changes from 0,5 to 1, but the image position changes from the center to the bottom left of the form.

Is there anything wrong, how could I do it?

Comment: This does indeed look pretty bad. Without understanding what is going on behind the FMX scenes (no pun intended), it seems you can solve this by adding an `OnProcess` handler to one of your animations and filling the handler with `yourImageControl.RecalcSize()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without understanding what is going on behind the FMX scenes (no pun intended), it seems you can solve this by adding an `OnProcess` handler to one of your animations and filling the handler with `yourImageControl.RecalcSize()`